# Name or service not known when using Dockerized Flask + MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I have an app that is composed of React, Flask, and MongoDB as a database.

My `docker-compose.yml` looks like

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  frontend:
    container_name: frontend
    build:
      context: frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3000:80"
  backend:
    build: ./backend
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    links:
      - db
  db:
    image: mongo:latest
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
```

The initial part of my flask `app.py` looks like

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS
from bson.objectid import ObjectId
import pymongo
import json
import ssh
import OpenSSL
import pprint
import os

application = Flask(__name__)
cors = CORS(application)

cors = CORS(application)
client = pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://mongodb:27017/')

db = client["my_db"]
```

However, when I `docker-compse build` and `docker-compose up`, I get

`backend_1   | pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: mongodb:27017: [Errno -2] Name or service not known`

when I make a request to the backend.

Any help please?

Comment: I think the hostname needs to be "db".

Comment: Do you mean `'mongodb://db:27017/'`?

Comment: That should work. The name should be the same as the name of the link you added.

Comment: It still gives me: `pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: db:27017: [Errno -2] Name or service not known`

Comment: Nevermind, I actually had a different hostname. It works now. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome glad I could help. Docker-compose should be very easy once you get the hang of it. :)

Comment: Thank you! I actually have another question. I would like to `mongoimport` a `json` file into the containerized database. Would you be able to answer this here, or shall I make another question?

Comment: I think make a new one should be easier to answwer. Before you log a question I suggest try your luck at setting a volume and import it by referencing it in the location where the volume is mounted. Hope that helps.

Comment: @OpenBSDNinja Thanks for your thought. I was actually gonna try that but it gave me some error. Here is the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58264595/mongoimport-in-docker-compose-gives-me-cannot-start-service-error Thanks again!