# mongoimport in docker-compose gives me 'Cannot start service' error

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I have an app that is composed of React, Flask, and MongoDB as a database.

What I tried to do was importing (`mongoimport`) some json files to the MongoDB database when I `docker-compose build`.

In my root directory, I created a directory called `mongo-seed` and I put all json files that I tried to import to the database along with the `import.sh` that looks like:

```
mongoimport --host <my_host_name> --db <my_db_name> --collection profiles --type json --file /mongo-seed/profiles.json --jsonArray
mongoimport --host <my_host_name> --db <my_db_name> --collection releases --type json --file /mongo-seed/releases.json --jsonArray
mongoimport --host <my_host_name> --db <my_db_name> --collection employees --type json --file /mongo-seed/employees.json --jsonArray
```

and my `docker-compose.yml` looks like:

```
# Docker Compose
version: '3.7'

services:
  frontend:
    container_name: frontend
    build:
      context: frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3000:80"
  backend:
    build: ./backend
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    links:
      - db
  db:
    image: mongo:latest
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
  mongo-seed:
    image: mongo:latest
    links:
      - "db"
    volumes:
      - ./mongo-seed:/mongo-seed
    command:
     /mongo-seed/import.sh
```

However, when I `docker-compose build` and then `docker-compose up`, I get

```
ERROR: for mongo-seed_1  Cannot start service mongo-seed: error while creating mount source path '/host_mnt/c/Users/<...>/Desktop/<root>/mongo-seed': mkdir /host_mnt/c: file exists

ERROR: for mongo-seed  Cannot start service mongo-seed: error while creating mount source path '/host_mnt/c/Users/<...>/Desktop/<root>/mongo-seed': mkdir /host_mnt/c: file exists
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you sure that directory isn't created by default? Perhaps try mounting the directory you wanna import from to /tmp and see if you can import from there?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue/nuisance in the Windows version of Docker. There are multiple things you can try.

1. Reset credentials: Even if your password hasn't changed, users have reported that this worked for them. In Settings > Shared Drives, at the bottom there is a button to reset.
2. If you don't mind any existing volumes be discarded, you can try `docker-compose up -V <any other options you specify such as -d>`. This will recreate anonymous volumes instead of reclaiming old ones.
3. A simple `docker volume prune` has also worked for some, but this will delete all unused volumes and is not recommended because some of them might have data that you might need to be reclaimed later.

All of the above and more are mentioned [in this discussion](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1560). The discussion also throws in this useful guide on [how to use a directory with Windows' Docker](http://support.divio.com/en/articles/646695-how-to-use-a-directory-outside-c-users-with-docker-toolbox-docker-for-windows).